# Mappear objeto con un response de un select C#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentado hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una clase **"objClass"** y quiero mappear mi objeto en el resultado de una consulta.
Por ejemplo:

```
// CLASE
public class objClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}

// CONSULTA
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id = X", conexion);
objClass obj = new objClass();
adp.Fill(ibj)
```

Y una vez mappeado el **"obj"** poder acceder a los datos:

```
// OBJ MAPEADO
int idObj = obj.id
string nombreObj = obj.nombre;

console.log("El id es:" + idObj);
console.log("El nombre es:" + nombreObj);
```

Sé que la cosa no es tal cual la muestro, pero estoy algo perdido y no he podido encontrar cómo hacerlo.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar la librería Dapper

Es un mapeador de objetos entre la consulta a tu base de datos y tu modelo `objClass`

Ejemplo:

```
string querySql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM tabla WHERE id = @X;"
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conexion))
{
   var tabla = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<objClass>(querySql, new { X = 1 });

   Console.WriteLine(tabla.id);
   Console.WriteLine(tabla.nombre);

 }
```

En términos de velocidad es prácticamente tan rápido como usar un lector de datos ADO.NET.

Puedes ver la documentación y algunos ejemplos en https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper